# how trigger button click

Tags: button, triggers, click

hi i have little english so maybe i can write wrong sory :)

i have a contact form it open with slideUp effect when click mail icon that's code

```
<div class="header_top_but closed resp-tab">
            <i class="sagform fa fa-envelope faa-shake animated"></i>
            <div class="header_top_but_arrow"></div>
        </div>
```

it's java is like this

```
(function ($) { 
    $('.header_top_but').bind('click', function () { 
        var headerTopBut = $(this), 
            headerTopButArrow = headerTopBut.find('> span'), 
            headerTopOuter = headerTopBut.parents('.header_top').find('.header_top_outer');

        if (headerTopBut.hasClass('opened')) {
            headerTopOuter.slideUp();

            headerTopButArrow.removeClass('cmsms_top_arrow').addClass('cmsms_bot_arrow');

            headerTopBut.removeClass('opened').addClass('closed');
        } else if (headerTopBut.hasClass('closed')) {
            headerTopOuter.slideDown();

            headerTopButArrow.removeClass('cmsms_bot_arrow').addClass('cmsms_top_arrow');

            headerTopBut.removeClass('closed').addClass('opened');
        }
    } );
} )(jQuery);
```

ok i want to that
how can do slideup my contact form when i click "contact me"

```
<div class="cmsms_column one_fourth">
                                        <div id="cmsms_button_5655b197e4739" class="button_wrap">
                                            <a href="dersler.aspx?id=1" class="cmsms_button cmsms-icon-calendar-3">
                                            <span>contact me!</span>
                                            </a>
                                            </div>
                                    </div>
```

i thing i can use trigger but i can't it please help

Answer (score 0):

If I understood it right, you just have to give an id (or a class) to "contact me":

`<span id="yourspanid">contact me!</span>`

Then add to JS:

```
$(document).ready(
  function(){

    $("#yourspanid").click(
      function() {
        //paste here the script that opens the form
    });

});
```

Make sure your script is inside "document ready".

Comment: thanks for answer anna but i tried it in javascript there are some class and my contact me haven't this class so it not work

Comment: Sorry, but I don´t get it. You cannot add an id to the span element? Or you did it but it does not work?

Make sure you place the script inside

´$(document).ready(
function(){});´

Comment: i have tried document.ready like you write bu not work it wrote it in head tag